# How to use cursor style:ns-resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

Where can I use the **cursor** style: **`ns-resize`**?

Do I have to **define an event[script]** describing the functionality of the cursor. **On what html objects** can I use a cursor with this style?

This question is very important for how to use cursors with **dragging functionality** i.e. for the following cursor styles-

```
move
col-resize
row-resize
n-resize
s-resize
e-resize
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style of the cursor makes absolutely no difference whatsoever. You can put `ns-resize` on your entire document if you really want to, although I don't think your visitors will think much of your site if you do.

If you have an element for which you have programmed a resize function triggered by dragging something, *then* you may put the `ns-resize` cursor (or the appropriate one) on that handle to illustrate to the user that they can do that.

Comment: Kolink, Thanx I thought so.
But can you help me with a **sample example** of that resize event?
I'd be highly benefitted.

Comment: Well... no, since I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: kolink, I just want some help in coding a resize event. At least give me **some hint in terms of an example** of the resize event I mean any implementation of the resize event. Can you help me out?